# Semantic UI popup position far off

Tags: jquery, css, semantic-ui

I'm trying to use the Semantic UI's popup module and it never worked properly in terms of positioning on my project as it is on the demos. I tried a few hacks (setting position to `relative` etc.) but had no luck; Here is a fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/smt94eox/
In which I intended to show popup on top left of the button as it is hovered:

```
$('#smile').popup({
    inline: true,
    hoverable: true, 
    position: 'top left'
});
```

But upon hover, the popup is shown on the bottom of the page. 
Anyone knows why and how to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### According to the [docs](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/examples)

You don't need the `inline` option

> Using the setting inline: true will let Semantic know to display the
>   next sibling ui popup element after the activator.

If you remove the inline option and make sure there is space for the popup, it will show correctly. http://jsfiddle.net/smt94eox/1/

### HTML - Just using "margin" to create some space for the popup

```
<div id="smile" class="ui labeled icon button" title="You can see this" style="margin:100px">
    <i class="smile icon"></i>Click me first
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$('#smile').popup({
    hoverable: true, 
    position: 'top left'
});
```

Comment: I see, I completely forgot to make space for the pop up. Thank you!